# UPDATE with INNER JOIN fails but related SELECT statement works

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join

Is there a reason why the following UPDATE statement produces an error

```
UPDATE `t1`
INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`id`=`t1`.`t2_id`
INNER JOIN `t3` ON `t2`.`t3_id` = `t3`.`id` AND `t3`.`a_id` = '123'
WHERE `t2`.`date` > '2012-08-14'
    AND `t2`.`status` = 'pending'
SET `t1`.`active` = '0';
```

The error I get is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `t2`.`date` > '2012-08-14' AND `t2`.`statu' at line 4
```

The following (related) SELECT statement works okay

```
SELECT `t1`.*
FROM `t1`
INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`id`=`t1`.`t2_id`
INNER JOIN `carer` ON `t2`.`t3_id` = `t3`.`id` AND `t3`.`a_id` = '123'
WHERE `t2`.`date` > '2012-08-14'
    AND `t2`.`status` = 'pending'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MySQL [`UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references  
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...  
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

Use this:

```
UPDATE `t1`
INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t2`.`id`=`t1`.`t2_id`
INNER JOIN `t3` ON `t2`.`t3_id` = `t3`.`id` AND `t3`.`a_id` = '123'

SET `t1`.`active` = '0'

WHERE `t2`.`date` > '2012-08-14'
    AND `t2`.`status` = 'pending' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Syntax to do it:

```
UPDATE r
INNER JOIN ENGING_DERIVE r
FROM ENGING_DERIVE
SET r.TUNING_PERFORM = r.BORE * r.STROKE
WHERE t.ID = t.ID;
```